# how to view class diagram for a spring project using spring IDE

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, class-diagram

I am working on a project which is based on spring framework and all dependencies have been defined in the xml files as beans. I need to see diagram of classes and dependencies between them using Spring IDE . This tool can show diagram of all classes with dependencies which have been defined in the xml as beans. Can any one help me in knowing how to do that. How can i see the class diagram using spring IDE..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

if you are using springsource tool suite (STS) you can view that from the Spring Explorer view by selecting your project and right click on the app-config xml file and select "Open dependency graph".

To open the Spring explorer view follow: Window->Show View -> Other -> Spring -> Spring Explorer

I hope it halped you. :)

Comment: I did not find app-config file anywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

Spring IDE based Eclipse. So you could find enough plugin over the web. eUML2 is one of that. http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try a UML plugin for Eclipse like Object Aid http://www.objectaid.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think your question might be a little unclear, it is to me anyway.  You asked how to diagram the classes/dependencies **that have been defined in XML as beans**.

I'm not aware of anything in the Spring IDE (aka Eclipse plus Spring add-ons) that will look at its configuration and map what it sees there, but ObjectAid and eUML2 and [Omondo](http://www.ejb3.org/) will diagram classes and dependencies, but they don't won't look at what is defined in your XML to find out what classes to map, they will map everything you tell them to map.

Answer (score 0):

Use applicationContext.xml/web-context.xml or select any bean and right click -> Open Beans graph